# C# How to Insert Data in a 2 created Dynamic Textbox with different Column name value

Tags: c#

How to insert data if i create two dynamic textboxes and store each value in 1 row my database table name is dbo.test and inside is test varchar(50) and test1 varchar (50)

```
    Stack<TextBox> textboxes = new Stack<TextBox>();
    List<String> controlNames = new List<String>();


private void butSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[0], true)[0];
        TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[1], true)[0];

        foreach (TextBox controlNames in textboxes.OfType<TextBox>()) ;
        { 
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test_info", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", textBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
           
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Data Save");
        textboxes.Clear();
        refresh();

    }
```

If i put data in 2 textbox and textbox1 is example John and textbox 2 is James in the database it will only store John in both column. i need to store them on what value was input in every textbox.

This is the code to generate dynamic textbox. i use for loop so that every click it will add another two dynamic textbox if the user wants to add another data in the database like if he wants to add James and John in first row and want to add another row which name is Todd and Tedd something like that.

```
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            
            TextBox textadd1 = new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(textadd1);
            textadd1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            textadd1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            textadd1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Left, Top);
            textadd1.Name = "textBox1";
            textadd1.BringToFront();
            textadd1.Size = new Size(36, 24);
            textadd1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            textadd1.Text = "";
            textboxes.Push(textadd1);
            controlNames.Add(textadd1.Name);
           

            TextBox textadd2 = new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(textadd2);
            textadd2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            textadd2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            textadd2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            textadd2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, Top);
            textadd2.Name = "textBox";
            textadd2.BringToFront();
            textadd2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 12);
            textadd2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            textboxes.Push(textadd2);
            controlNames.Add(textadd2.Name);

            Top += 22;
            count--;
        }



    }
```

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_info]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

```
@test varchar(50),
@test1 varchar(50)
```

AS
BEGIN

```
    insert into [dbo].[test](test,test1)values(@test,@test1)
```

END // SQL

Comment: where is `controlNames` set values?

Comment: @LeiYang wait i will post it. please let me know

Comment: @LeiYang done i updated my post. i put also comments for you to see. thank you

Comment: please also share you sql contents for `test_info`

Comment: @LeiYang done i update the sql.

Comment: Change `textadd2.Name = "textBox";`   to:   `textadd2.Name = "textBox1";`

Comment: If i change  it to textadd2.Name = "textBox1";   the controlname to identify will be null save button  TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find(controlNames[0], true)[0];
            TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)Controls.Find(controlNames[1], true)[0];

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set fixed names to the textboxes. I don't know how C# manages this as you can't have two controls with the same name in the same container form, anyway, your issue is here in the code that adds new textboxes:

```
textadd1.Name = "textBox1";
--
textadd2.Name = "textBox";
```

That means that your variable `controlNames` will store something like
"textBox1"
"textBox"
"textBox1"
"textBox"
... and so on

You could fix this by providing aditional info to the names so that they are unique, like for example:

```
textadd1.Name = "textBox" + controlNames.Count
```

Apart from that, I don't understand why are you using count++, count--. But the above is at least one of the problems of your code.

Edit: as for the loop to insert the names in the database, you can do it with a loop on the controlNames variable. As you need to get them 2 by 2 one possible way would be

```
int n = 1;
while (n < controlNames.Count) {
// First we get the textboxes
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n-1], true)[0];
TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n], true)[0];
    
// Insert to db
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test_info", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", textBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();  
// We increment the iterator variable by 2
n = n + 2;
}
```

Notice in your snippet of code you always used `textBox1` (from `controlNames[0]`) and `textBox` (from `controlNames[1]`), and then inserted them in the database as many times as items you in `controlNames`.

Edit 2: Since it seems you have created 5 textboxes, the loop should look a little different from the one you posted as answer:

```
int n = 0; 
while (n < controlNames.Count)
{
// First we get the textboxes
TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n], true)[0];
TextBox textBox2 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n + 1], true)[0];
TextBox textBox3 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n + 2], true)[0];
TextBox textBox4 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n + 3], true)[0];
TextBox textBox5 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n + 4], true)[0];
//...
n = n + 5;
}
```

Please note that your controlNames array will be size 5, beginning in 0, that means if you do this

```
int n = 1;
...
controlNames[n-2] // would be controlNames[-1]
```

this is what raises the "index out of range" error. Position -1, -2 and so on don't exist.

Anyway, this doesn't seem making sense to me. Are you creating 5 textboxes, then another 5 (total 10), and so on? Or you need to have only 5 textboxes for your parameters? In this case the idea would be to loop through your 5 textboxes from 0 to 4, not including +1, +2 or -1, -2... in the while loop. This would look like:

```
for (int n = 0; n < controlNames.Count; n++)
{
// We get each texbox and fill the bd parameter
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n], true)[0];
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test" + n,  myTextBox.Text); // here you should perform some change to only add n to @test if its > 0
}
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", label1.Text);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Comment: yeah. my count++ and count-- is not being use here sorry about that. but anyway textadd1.Name = "textBox" + textadd1.Count and it gives me error " Operator ' + ' cannot be applied to operands of type string and metho Group "

Comment: Can you try textadd1.Name = "textBox" + textadd1.Count.ToString();?

Comment: if i add .ToString() it will say error is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I edited the answer. What you should use is controlNames.Count, not textadd (which is a textbox). Sorry I missed the name of the variable.

Comment: yes that got it. thank so much it will get now the value and names. but hey i have this 1 last concern is it ok?

Comment: Nice! Which last concern?

Comment: . it can save now and everything is working according to the details we input in the textbox., but there is this one problem i encounter after the the data save in db. it replicate the information or row.  instead only 1 row. it will create 2 row with same value like,  row 1 = james john.  row 2 = james john. is there any codes i use to why this duplication happen? i just only want to save 1 row at a time. can you help me why it is happening all my codes is posted

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the loop you made to iterate through the textboxes. What you really want to do is to get the textboxes content 2 by 2 for each execution of the stored procedure. You could perform this with a while, for example. I'll try to update again, in the meanwhile you could have a look at your for() statement

Comment: Ohh i see.,  thank you so much it will a big help for me to finalize my codes hoping for your response

Comment: Done! Hope it also helps you understand what was happening.

Comment: Hi May i know why did you put [n-1] and since im trying to add more columns  5 textboxes dynamic what would be the value of this? n - 4?.  and can you explain also the iterator why you put + 2?

Comment: Hi! Because you create 2 textboxes each time, one for each parámetros, isn't that? Then you want to use 2 of your textboxes each time you save on bd. If you follow the iterations: first time you access controlNames[0] and controlNames[1]. Next time you access controlNames[2] and controlNames[3]. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    foreach (var controlNames in textboxes.OfType<TextBox>()) ;
    { 
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test_info", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", controlNames.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
       
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this will make error it will tell Procedure or function 'test_info' expects parameter '@test1', which was not supplied.'

Answer (score 0):

I Try This Codes and it give me Error . /  'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

```
        if (t1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }
        else
        {   

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("test_info", conn);
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test",  t1.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", t2.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test2", t3.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test3", t4.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test4", t5.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", label1.Text);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            int n = 1;
            while (n < controlNames.Count)
            {
                // First we get the textboxes
                TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n - 1], true)[0];
                TextBox textBox2 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n], true)[0];
                TextBox textBox3 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n - 2], true)[0];
                TextBox textBox4 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n - 3], true)[0];
                TextBox textBox5 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlNames[n - 4], true)[0];

                // Insert to db
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("test_info", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test2", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test3", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test4", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", label1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                // We increment the iterator variable by 2
                n = n + 5;
            }


            MessageBox.Show("Data Save");
            textboxes.Clear();
            refresh();
```

Comment: Im Trying to Duplicate original 5 Textboxes in each column name. after pressing the button to add dynamic textbox. it will replicate the 5 original textboxes which will be in a row format.  the problem is when i save the data to the database it will give me this error. " Index is out of range

Comment: Hi again. I updated my answer again since I just noticed your own answer.